# Cannont install super boot manager

Tags: customization, burg

I want to customize my plymouth, by using super boot manager. I added the repo and then updated, there is no problem at all.

After I tryed to install super-boot-manager something went wrong.
I get this error:

```
whoops@whoops-N148P:~$ sudo apt-get install super-boot-manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable   
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 super-boot-manager : Depends: plowshare (>= 1~svn1525) but it is not going to be     installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 0):

**To install Super Boot Manager in Ubuntu 14.10:**

1. I wasn't able to get the ppa working, so I had to download  the binaries from the project [website](http://www.sourceslist.eu/burg-2/super-boot-manager-buc-version-download-installation/). If any of these links are broken, you can search for them on launchpad. I had to do this for [buc 0.5.2](https://launchpad.net/~ingalex/+archive/ubuntu/super-boot-manager/+build/3551622).
   I've circled the ones I downloaded in the link below:
   [image: downloads]
2. Open the terminal <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> and paste:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i *.deb
   ```
3. When that's finished installing super-boot-manager and buc, run:

   ```
   sudo apt-get -f install
   ```
4. It should install a new version of plymouth as well as plowshare.